# HTML - Adding scrollbar to table body?

Tags: html, css

I have a table which has some content in the body. I want to add a scrollbar to the `body`. I can't get it working; I called body to class and tried to add a scrollbar, but it won't appear. So I'm looking for a solution. Here's my code:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
var total = 0;

function sitaSeen(img, name, condition, price) {
  $('tbody').append("<tr><td><img src=" + img + "></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + condition + "</td><td>$" + price + "</td><td><span>X</span></td></tr>");
  total += price;
  $('#total').empty();
  $('#total').append("Total: $" + total);
}
$('.papa').on('click', 'tr span', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<h2>System</h2>
<button onclick="sitaSeen('https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpovbSsLQJf3qr3czxb49KzgL-KmsjwPKvBmm5D19V5i_rEprP5gVO8v11lZj-gIYbDclRqMA7Zq1S7lOm-0Za6753KmHoxvnQh5y7ZyhWxiRwecKUx0iL1oy6z/60fx60f','M9 Bayonet | Doppler','Battle Scarred',70)">Click</button>
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Logo</h2>
      <h2 id="total">Total: $0</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <table class="centered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th data-field="pic"></th>
            <th data-field="id">Item</th>
            <th data-field="name">Conditon</th>
            <th data-field="price">Price</th>
            <th data-field="delete"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
          <tbody class="papa">
          </tbody>
      </table>
      <button>seen</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You do not have enough content for having a scroll in the body! Try to add many text or whatever, and you will see that scroll will appear by default!

Comment: Can I somehow change that "limit"?

Comment: At first I had there on the modal comes the scroll, I removed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using **position: fixed** css property, your html element will be out of It's normal flow through document. That's why a scrollbar does not appear on document.

A solution would be not to use **position: fixed** property, I suppose you would like to have it for to center the div#modal. You have lot's of other options to use for centering an html element.

[Refer to this article](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: Alright, it kinda works, but now how could I do something like it goes bigger if I add items & then comes the scroll when there is enough? Basically they wont go over the modal

Comment: @AleksKpur can you please explain it more?